# Issue in passing user access token in React JS to render the Power BI report

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, azure-ad-msal, powerbi-embedded, msal-react

I am building a web application using React JS where I have implemented user authentication using `Microsoft MSAL JS` library. I am also trying to embed power bi report using `[powerbi-client-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react)` library. In my code triage and display desired report based on runtime attribute values, I am trying to pass the user access token (Aad token) which I obtain after user authentication. In my console log window, I am able to grab that access token as a plain string which I hold in a variable and pass it further in `<PowerBIEmbed />`.

The issue is - with that variable the report doesn't display but if I pass the access token as plain string (hard coded), report displays fine. So I assume there is no any permission related issue.

Below is my code snippet.

My expectation is to display or render desired report while passing that access token obtained after user authentication and getting it stored in any sort of variable and passing in `<PowerBIEmbed />`

**Code in my authConfig.js;**

```
export const pbiToken = {
    scopes: ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All"],
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
import { models } from 'powerbi-client';
import { pbiToken } from '../authConfig';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

export const EmbedReport = (props) => {
  const [powerBIAccessToken, setPowerBIAccessToken] = useState(null);
  const reportId = props.reportId;
  const embedUrl = props.embedUrl;
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

  const getPowerBIToken = async () => {
    try {
      // Acquire an access token for Power BI using the scopes from authConfig
      const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: pbiToken.scopes,
        account: accounts[0],
      });
      if (response.accessToken) {
        console.log("reading token", response.accessToken);
        setPowerBIAccessToken(JSON.stringify(response.accessToken));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle token acquisition errors
      console.error("Error acquiring Power BI token:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const isLoggedIn = accounts.length > 0;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      getPowerBIToken();
    }
  }, [accounts.length]);

  return (
    <>
      {powerBIAccessToken ? (
        <PowerBIEmbed
          embedConfig={{
            type: "report",
            id: reportId,
            embedUrl: embedUrl.href,
            accessToken: powerBIAccessToken,
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
            settings: {
              panes: {
                filters: {
                  expanded: false,
                  visible: false,
                },
              },
              background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
            },
          }}
          eventHandlers={
            new Map([
              [
                "rendered",
                function () {
                  console.log("Report rendered");
                },
              ],
              [
                "error",
                function (event) {
                  console.log(event.detail);
                },
              ],
              ["visualClicked", () => console.log("visual clicked")],
            ])
          }
          cssClassName={"reportClass"}
          getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
            window.report = embeddedReport;
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <p>'hello'</p> //NOTE: this line or condition is part of triage and can be gone later
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default EmbedReport;
```

**Update:**
when I try to resolve my issue, I am getting below error:

```
{message: 'LoadReportFailed', detailedMessage: 'Fail to initialize - Could not resolve cluster', errorCode: '403', level: 6, technicalDetails: {…}}

detailedMessage: "Fail to initialize - Could not resolve cluster"
errorCode: "403"
level: 6
message: "LoadReportFailed"
technicalDetails: {requestId: '2e3c92c0-098b-40d6-9c22-306a6b555866', errorInfo: undefined}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Refer to the GitHub repos mentioned below, and let me know if your scenario is different, or if you're facing any errors in specific while implementing.

Comment: @KotanaSai, thank you for providing these insight. Before I delve myself into this exploration, I want to say that in my code snippet above, I am getting and storing access token in variable `powerBIAccessToken` and as we see, I am assigning that variable to `accessToken` attribute. But strange thing I am facing is - if I copy that access token string directly to `accessToken` attribute, the report displays perfectly. (meaning my token looks valid). It is just when I assign it to variable, rendering stops or breaks. How do I do work around this situation? Thanks again.

Comment: I think the problem is with `JSON.stringify(response.accessToken)`.  The accessToken in the response is of type string. Can you give a shot by setting the accessToken without JSON stringifying `setPowerBIAccessToken(response.accessToken)`

Comment: When I tried passing the accessToken using JSON.stringify, Got Error "Get Report failed". I guess there is some minor mistake in the code and no wrong in the approach. If the issue still approach, you can create a sample running application, for anyone to look into it and identify the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Error you're facing might be because of either Bad Access token or embed type doesn't matches the token type. Refer [troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot#typical-errors-when-embedding-for-power-bi-users) documentation for more details on error.

If you're embedding report using Master user authentication method, Refer to [React Developer Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/React-TS/Embed%20for%20your%20organization).

If you're embedding report using service principal authentication method, Refer to my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/KotanaSai21/powerbi-embedded-React-demo)